# Android: Switch with text and custom view

Tags: android, canvas, view, switch-statement

I need to develop a button like in this picture:

[image]
[image]

How can I customize Switch? Or if it is not possible, how to implement this custom view?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/toogle_switch"
    android:text=""
    android:textOn=""
    android:textOff="" />
```

toogle_switch.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/on" android:state_checked="true"></item>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/off" android:state_checked="false"></item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:switchMinWidth="56dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:text="Switch1:"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textOff="OFF"
        android:textOn="ON"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.r_layout);
Switch sb = new Switch(this);
sb.setTextOff("OFF");
sb.setTextOn("ON");
sb.setChecked(true);
layout.addView(sb);


Switch sw = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
sw.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // The toggle is enabled
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled
        }
    }
});
```